# SVN splitting dilemma

Tags: svn, maven

I have a JavaEE project as follows:

- hms2 (Maven parent pom)
- hms2-ear
- hms2-ejb
- hms2-web

Should i use one SVN repository for all, or should i split up into 4 SVN repositories?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use maven and your components follow different development lifecycles you can split the SVN repo too but in conjunction with an internal maven repo (such as Artifactory or Nexus) so you let the developers be able to build their component without sources.

If your application is a single application (even if layered for separation of responsibilities purpose) you should not split.

Seeing that you are using maven modules (with parent POM) I think you are in the second case.

Comment: Second case as in i should not be spliting?

Comment: Yes, in the second case you shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

I would say use one repository. I don't see what you will gain from having several, apart from some complexity. Also the projects are related to each other(at least thematically).

Answer (score 1):

Keep them in one repo as they seem related and moving things from one repo to the other (with history) is quite the nightmare in svn.